# Return sum of all sales values and sales value for each product

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

I have a query that will be like this

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    ProductSales,
    ProductLocationName
FROM
    ProductLocation
WHERE
    ProductLine=@ProductLine
```

So my sample results could be like this

```
ProductID    ProductSales   ProductLocationName
1            $2             Boston
1            $2             Chicago
2            $8             Boston
```

There are some `productID/ProductSales` combinations which are repeated if the `ProductLocationName` is different but what I need to return is the following:

I need to return what I am returning above in my sample results but also in addition to this I need to sum all `ProductSales` values except for duplicate `ProductID/ProductSales` combinations.

Example from above:

```
ProductID 1 + ProductID 2
$2 + $8 = $10
```

Note that I did not add $2 twice since that `prodID/Sales` value is repeated in the results, however I still need to return the 3 rows above since I have to show all 3 rows in my repeater.

Hope I am being clear, in addition `ProductID` & `ProductLocation` (and there will be other columns included in my query), I need

1. `ProductSales` (as displayed in `SampleResults` above) for each `ProductID`. I know that `SUM(ProductSales)` will get me this.
2. `SUM` of `ProductSales` for all unique `ProductID` values ($2 + $8 = $10)

I would like to do all of this in the same stored procedure if possible.

My main concern is how to get point 2, meaning SUM all of the `ProductSales` values, in my example $2+$8

Please let me know if you need any more information, this is  my first post here.

Answer (score 0):

To do this correctly, you will need a subquery for the calculation:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductSales, ProductLocationName, t.SumProductSales
FROM ProductLocation pl cross join
     (select sum(ProductSales) as SumProductSales
      from (select productId, max(ProductSales) as ProductSales
            from ProductionLocation pl
            group by productId
           ) p
     ) t
WHERE ProductLine=@ProductLine
```

You need to watch out for different products that have the same value for ProductSales.

Comment: thanks, how do i do the same for average (AVG)? or should that be another post?

Comment: Just replace `Sum(ProductSales) as SumProductSales` with `avg(ProductSales) as AvgProductSales` and use that field in the query.  You can actually include both if you like.